# How do I duplicate a resource reference in code behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamicresource

In my application, I have a color resources. I have one element that uses that color as a dynamic resource in xaml.

```
  <Window x:Class="ResourcePlay.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="425">
     <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyColor">Red</Color>
     </Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="80" Margin="10">
           <Rectangle.Fill>
              <SolidColorBrush x:Name="TopBrush" Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}"/>
           </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Height="80" Margin="10">
           <Rectangle.Fill>
              <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BottomBrush"/>
           </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
     </Grid>
  </Window>
```

In the code, I want to duplicate this resource reference.

```
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Media;

  namespace ResourcePlay {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
           InitializeComponent();

           // I want to copy the resource reference, not the color.
           BottomBrush.Color = TopBrush.Color;

           // I'd really rather do something like this.
           var reference = TopBrush.GetResourceReference(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty);
           BottomBrush.SetResourceReference(reference);

           // I want this to change the colors of both elements
           Resources["MyColor"] = Colors.Green;
        }
     }
  }
```

However, SetResourceReference only works for FrameworkElements or FrameworkContentElements. SolidColorBrush is just a Freezable. Also, I have no idea how to *get* a resource reference in code behind.

Is there a way to do this in WPF so that both of the colors change at the same time? In my real application, the problem isn't quite so simple, so I can't just add a second DynamicResource in xaml.

Comment: Please explain, in precise detail, why it is you aren't simply declaring the `SolidColorBrush` as a resource itself and then using that for the `Fill` properties of the elements where you want it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the SolidColorBrush here is a proxy for a custom Freezable subclass I'm using in my application. The real object is paramaterized for Dependency Injection, so I can't create the object in xaml.

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote an issue, as this was my exact question also. This thread provided a solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il Vic suggested using reflection. Expanding on that, I was able to build some extension methods for DependencyObject that do what I want. I don't really like using reflection in code, and if someone else knows a better way to implement this, I'd love to see it. At least this will be helpful whenever I'm trying to debug DynamicResources from code behind.

```
  public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
  {
     public static object GetDynamicResourceKey(this DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty prop)
     {
        // get the value entry from the depencency object for the specified dependency property
        var dependencyObject = typeof(DependencyObject);
        var dependencyObject_LookupEntry = dependencyObject.GetMethod("LookupEntry", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var entryIndex = dependencyObject_LookupEntry.Invoke(obj, new object[] { prop.GlobalIndex });
        var effectiveValueEntry_GetValueEntry = dependencyObject.GetMethod("GetValueEntry", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var valueEntry = effectiveValueEntry_GetValueEntry.Invoke(obj, new object[] { entryIndex, prop, null, 0x10 });

        // look inside the value entry to find the ModifiedValue object
        var effectiveValueEntry = valueEntry.GetType();
        var effectiveValueEntry_Value = effectiveValueEntry.GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var effectiveValueEntry_Value_Getter = effectiveValueEntry_Value.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
        var rawEntry = effectiveValueEntry_Value_Getter.Invoke(valueEntry, new object[0]);

        // look inside the ModifiedValue object to find the ResourceReference
        var modifiedValue = rawEntry.GetType();
        var modifiedValue_BaseValue = modifiedValue.GetProperty("BaseValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var modifiedValue_BaseValue_Getter = modifiedValue_BaseValue.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
        var resourceReferenceValue = modifiedValue_BaseValue_Getter.Invoke(rawEntry, new object[0]);

        // check the ResourceReference for the original ResourceKey
        var resourceReference = resourceReferenceValue.GetType();
        var resourceReference_resourceKey = resourceReference.GetField("_resourceKey", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var resourceKey = resourceReference_resourceKey.GetValue(resourceReferenceValue);

        return resourceKey;
     }

     public static void SetDynamicResourceKey(this DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty prop, object resourceKey)
     {
        var dynamicResource = new DynamicResourceExtension(resourceKey);
        var resourceReferenceExpression = dynamicResource.ProvideValue(null);
        obj.SetValue(prop, resourceReferenceExpression);
     }
  }
```

The second method uses `DynamicResourceExtension` to avoid some nastiness with Activator, but the first method feels incredibly brittle.

I can use these methods in my original example as follows:

```
  public MainWindow() {
     InitializeComponent();

     var key = TopBrush.GetDynamicResourceKey(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty);
     BottomBrush.SetDynamicResourceKey(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, key);

     Resources["MyColor"] = Colors.Green;
  }
```

This will work for any DependencyProperty, provided it is set to a DynamicResource when we try to get the resource key. A little more finesse would be needed for production code.

Comment: I don't like using massively reflection in my code too, but you made a very good digging and exploring work in standard assemblies! Well done!

Comment: This worked like a champ for me in .net 4.6 - It might cause me some grief later on, but did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need an internal object called `ResourceReferenceExpression`. It is used in DynamicResourceExtention.

This is the code you can use:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BottomBrush.SetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty,
        Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"), "MyColor"));

    Resources["MyColor"] = Colors.Green;
}
```

Use it carefully! Since `ResourceReferenceExpression` is internal, maybe there will be a reason (maybe a wrong use of that object can lead to memory leaks).

Comment: This is _almost_ what I'm looking for. Is there any way to get the `ResourceReferenceExpression` that the `TopBrush` is using, and then use that same expression (or a copy) for the bottom one? I'd rather not have to hardcode the "MyColor" for the second brush - I want it to use whatever the first brush is using.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to get a `ResourceReferenceExpression`: we are talking about an internal object, not a public one. Probably you should change your approach to the problem. Maybe you can consider to put a `SolidColorBrush` as a resource (as Peter is suggesting). Or maybe you can set both brushes color in your XAML and not in your code.