# How can I get a resource key from an object with C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

Now,I have a .xaml file like this:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Content="{DynamicResource resource1}" Height="50" Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

and I loaded it by `XamlReader.Load(stream)`. Our software allows the user to edit this loaded page, so I must tell the user in my property bar what the current button's Content property value is, or what resources are referenced.

I stored some strings in ResourceDictionary, Just an example.

```
<Application
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

    <System:String x:Key="resource1">test1</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="resource2">test2</System:String>

</Application.Resources>
```

Now I want to get this resource key("resource1") to display to user. I can get this element: Button, I can get its "Content" property value：test1, but now, I just want to know which resource it references? Is there any way to do it in addition to parsing strings?

Comment: not sure your are on the right way ? why thiis external file loaded with XamlReader ? why in a grid ? which KEY do you want ? because there are not x:KEY in your sample ?

Comment: this is not working ....BindingOperations.GetBinding(target, ContentControl.ContentProperty);
so think does not work for Content ==> btw i do not understood why you want to get all these....you are loosing all the power of wpf...good luck

Comment: I found the answer in the link below [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240528/how-do-i-duplicate-a-resource-reference-in-code-behind-in-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240528/how-do-i-duplicate-a-resource-reference-in-code-behind-in-wpf)